# Is it possible to rewrite subfolder to subdomain with IIS7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have an asp.net application on sub domain sub.domain.com I want to access this application by typing www.domain.com/sub is it possible with IIS7?

Comment: Do you need to do this automatically or are you happy to manually configure this?

Comment: Also, do you have an existing application at www.domain.com/ that you want to preserve?

Comment: I can do it manually. And yes I have an application working on www.domain.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're happy to manually configure the application at each subdomain:

- In IIS Manager, go to Sites, and select your www.domain.com site.
- Right click it, "Add Application" and specify the alias "sub" and point the physical path to the same location as sub.domain.com
- Select the same application pool as the sub.domain.com site.

Alternatively you could set up a redirect by creating a new Virtual Directory in your www.domain.com site, then dropping in a default.html file that does a http redirect.

A posher (and more transparent to the user) redirect could be done like so:

1. Open an elevated command prompt
2. run the following command:

   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "nameofsite/virtualdirectoryname" -section:system.webServer/httpRedirect -enabled:true -destination:destinationofredirect -commitpath:apphost

I lifted that from: http://www.andrewwestgarth.co.uk/Blog/post/2008/07/31/Creating-Http-Redirects-in-IIS7-on-Virtual-Directories-like-IIS6.aspx