# creating subdomain and setting dns record

Tags: dns

I want a subdomain cdn. I have created the subdomain and set this a-record

cdn.ski.eu 185.28.56.52 A

What it does is go to:
ski.eu/cdn

I would like

cdn.ski.eu

Answer (score 0):

Assuming of course you are referring to the URI used in the HTTP application protocol. This would require a redirect 302 or 303 of some kind (server side) to indicate that http://ski.eu/cdn should be redirected to http://cdn.ski.eu.

Below are some similar questions that may supply you with the answer.

[Is it possible to rewrite subfolder to subdomain with IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924693/is-it-possible-to-rewrite-subfolder-to-subdomain-with-iis7)

[Redirecting Subdirectory to Subdomain with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415896/redirecting-subdirectory-to-subdomain-with-htaccess)

[Pointing a subdomain to a subfolder using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588371/pointing-a-subdomain-to-a-subfolder-using-htaccess)